# Segment Tree - Finding all subarray sums

Tags: segment-tree

Suppose we have an array that's like [1, 2, 3, 4], if I created a segment tree for that array we'd get something like: [null, 10, 3, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4], so all of the subarray sums would exactly what we have on the segment tree.

However, if our input array is like [1, 2, 3], our segment tree would be something like: [null, 6, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0], with the trailing 0 since we don't have a complete binary tree due to 3 (the array's length) not being a power of 2.

Unlike in the first example, since our binary tree isn't complete, we run into duplicate ranges. In our tree: [null, 6, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0], the 2nd last 3 and the last 3 represent the same range, since the right tree has a 0.

Is there any way to distinguish between this duplicate range? Or should I be using another data structure for a problem that's susceptible to this kind of segment tree duplicate range issue that I'm having with my second example?

Comment: "this type of problem" - What type is that?

Comment: @KellyBundy I've edited the post slightly, not too sure how to word it but I hope it helps with the clarity a little bit.